# Prevent OS from capturing Start and Alt+Tab buttons in a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to prevent the OS from capturing the Alt+Tab combo and Start button at least while in full-screen mode?

I know there would be some implications but for certain use cases (eg. VNC client) such an option would prove very useful.

Comment: I suspect (hope) that this is only possible with help from some component installed on the system and running outside the security sandbox.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking.. then again some specific software (like VMware/VirtualBox) does manage to do this. However, I too hope such a feature will never land in a browser, but I could see it in a Chrome packaged app with a dedicated manifest permission.

Comment: VMware and VirtualBox run with administrator privileges and load kernel components, so there's really *nothing* they can't do.  Admin rights shouldn't be needed for this, but you do need direct access to OS APIs, which means being outside the security sandbox.  And yes, an extension or packaged app should be able to get outside the sandbox (with user permission).

Comment: You'd probably be interested in kiosk mode on ChromeOS. It's in development here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/chromeos/kiosk_mode/&sq=package:chromium&type=cs